# Cannot update a file for my theme

Tags: themes, theme-options

I have a theme that automatically adds some widgets. I don't want them and so I tried to edit the Sidebar.php but it just fails and sends me to a page with message 404.
Here's the code block I am trying to delete from Sidebar.php:

```
<!-- sidebar south START -->
<div id="southsidebar" class="sidebar">
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('south_sidebar') ) : ?>

    <!-- archives -->
    <div class="widget">
        <h3>Archives</h3>
        <?php if(function_exists('wp_easyarchives_widget')) : ?>
            <?php wp_easyarchives_widget("mode=none&limit=6"); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <!-- meta -->
    <div class="widget">
        <h3>Meta</h3>
        <ul>
            <?php wp_register(); ?>
            <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<!-- sidebar south END -->
```

EDIT: So for now what I have done is I modified the css to hide southsidebar. But actually I want to use that div by adding other widgets.

Comment: can't you just delete the code between `<div id="southsidebar" class="sidebar">` the code block `</div>` and add your other widget that you want?

Comment: @Pontus I started with that but it is not letting me delete anything or even not commenting out.

Comment: where are you editing the file "sidebar.php" ? in the wordpress admin? or via FTP with an external editor?

Comment: @Ludovic Wordpress editor....

Comment: @Ludovic I was able to edit that page directly from my host's file editor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those widgets are added because you've specified none

Try adding a text widget with no content but spaces, you'll find all those hardcoded default 'widgets' dissappear

You should **never** use the built in editor in WordPress though, so use FTP/Shell/VCS instead

Comment: Good trick. Unfortunately that still leave me with an empty side-bar with borders. And my problem of modifying via editor still remains.

Comment: Well you should **never** use the editor in the backend of WordPress. Use FTP instead

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- sidebar south START -->
<div id="southsidebar" class="sidebar">
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('south_sidebar') ) : ?>
```

Insert yours widgets code here

```
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<!-- sidebar south END -->
```

File Permissions 
To edit a file through [the Built-in Editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins_Editor_SubPanel), the permissions for that file must be set to 666. You can change the permissions on files by using a FTP client program, web-based interface provided by your host, or from the command-line using telnet or ssh (secure shell). These options are dependent on the type of access your host offers.

Comment: I tried changing the Premission but after doing that it won't even load up the theme editor page. I am able to update Styles.css but no the sidebar.php. Both has same permission 644.

Comment: Also the document you pointed says: Note that if a file is not writeable the Update File button will not be available. But I can see the button and click it. There error shows up after that.